# Specifying default env for jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

Is there some way to tell jupyter notebook what the default conda env should be when creating new notebooks? Launching it on AWS Deep Learning AMI's gives me a pretty long list, but I really only care about one specific env.

[image]

Comment: Did you try activating the environment first and then opening jupyter notebook from the command line?

Comment: I did, no effect

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your terminal first and activate the virtual environment:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

or

```
$ conda activate venv
```

for conda environment.

And after that step, do the following:

```
$ jupyter notebook
```

And when you make a new script it should give you the option for chosing `python3/python2`, chose the one that solves your purpose. And this script will be using the activated environment. You can check it by importing a libraray specific to that environment.